# Отсутствие перевода на вкладках для сортировки ответов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Обнаружил отсутствие перевода здесь:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: OMG ... кто придумал этот дизайн?!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, думаю умельцы из англоязычного SO, как по мне то стало не очень удобно, без разделения вопроса и ответов)) но может это только мне так кажется)

Comment: @Andrew не только =/

Comment: @αλεχολυτ штош...

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, я не одинок)))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14327

Спасибо, добавил старый перевод:

> По дате публикации

После обновления движка появится.

Comment: Сорри за оффтоп - возможно ли добавить к голосованию ещё метку "Жирный плюс" ? то есть другими словами поощерить в два раза больше

Comment: @MaximLensky сейчас такого нету)

Comment: незя такое  вкрутить как то ? а то часто вижу "тебе Жирный плюс"  а на самом деле этот "Жирный" от "Обычного" ни чем не отличаются

Comment: @MaximLensky мы точно не можем. Можно такое попробовать на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) предложить. Но скорей всего не будут реализовывать.